# Redirect component adding strings to new URL

Tags: redirect

I have a Joomla 3.10.5 site that has recently been reorganized, so we are redirecting the old broken links to their new locations. However, every day when I reopen the component, the new URLs that I have added have query strings appended to the end. Some are short and some are long, and it seems to depend on how often the Expired URL is visited. Here are a few examples of the strings added to the end of the new URLs (that I input clean):

> ?view=category&id=9?view=article&id=28%3Atrainings&catid=9
>
> ?catid=13&id=136%3Alanguage-skills&view=article
>
> ?format=feed&id=15&type=rss&view=category
>
> ?id=15&view=category?view=category&id=15
>
> ?view=article&id=103:autism-classroom-store&catid=20?view=article&id=99:behavior-tools&catid=20?view=article&id=67:blank-schedule-forms&catid=20?view=article&id=65:opening-and-morning-circle-schedule&catid=20?view=article&id=63:free-schedules&catid=20?view=article&id=34:snack-time&catid=20?view=article&id=33:opening-materials&catid=20?view=article&id=32:schedules&catid=20

I've never observed this behavior before and have no idea what could be causing it. Appreciate any ideas!